# Google maps Javascript working for Chrome only

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've modified the google maps autocomplete autofill form from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) to include latitude and longitude while also combining some field values to enter into my database. However, while the code works in Chrome, it doesn't work for other browsers. In chrome, the relevant fields are being populated with the relevant data. In the other browsers, some of the input fields switch disabled off but no data is passed into the fields at all. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The relevant changes are below. Please help.

```
    var fullAddress = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }


        if (addressType == "street_number") {
            fullAddress[0] = val;
        } else if (addressType == "route") {
            fullAddress[1] = val;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("lat").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById("lng").value = place.geometry.location.lng();
    document.getElementById('fullAddress').value = fullAddress.join(" ");

    if (document.getElementById('fullAddress').value !== "") {
        document.getElementById('fullAddress').disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: First step is to open the console in other browsers (usually CTRL+SHIFT+i - or CMD+SHIFT+i on a mac) and check for errors. Also, you should define what you mean when you say `it doesn't work`

Comment: Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` button or Ctrl+M) are for **runnable** examples. If your example isn't runnable, just use a code block (the `{}` button, or Ctrl+K).

Comment: In this line document.getElementById(addressType).value Try converting addressType to a string first. May have something to do with this related question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366735/when-do-i-need-quotes-for-document-getelementbyid

Comment: feedback much appreciated. still learning the ropes around here.